# How can i prevent the wifi to auto disconnects when idle

Tags: wireless, lock-screen, idle, disconnect

After few minutes when my laptop is idle it's automatically locks the screen and disconnects from the wireless network and then reconnects when I unlock the screen.
Is it possible to change this thing? (so my downloads can keep going while my laptop is idle)